# How do scoping and visibility rules in VHDL work?

Tags: overloading, vhdl

I have two tools that disagree about whether the procedure call `p;` is ambiguous. If `p[boolean]` and `p[integer]` are homographs, I think `p[boolean]` should be hidden inside the unlabeled process. However, in LRM 12.3, there is this definition of homographs:

> Each of two declarations is said to be a homograph of the other if and only if both declarations have the same designator, and they denote different named entities, and either overloading is allowed for at most one of the two, or overloading is allowed for both declarations **and they have the same parameter and result type profile** (see 4.5.1).

Since the two procedures have different parameter types, I conclude they are not homographs of each other, and so I expect calling `p;` should be ambiguous. Modelsim disagrees (this code compiles and runs there), but another tool based on the Verific parser claims that the `p;` procedure call is ambiguous. Which tool has interpreted the LRM correctly?

```vhdl
entity DFlopTop is
end entity DFlopTop;
 
architecture behave of DFlopTop is
  procedure p(a : boolean := false) is
  begin
  report "p = " & boolean'image(a) & " " & p[boolean]'path_name;
  end procedure p;
begin
 
process is
  procedure p(a : integer := 2) is
  begin
  report "p = " & integer'image(a) & " " & p[integer]'path_name;
  end procedure p;
 
begin
  p;
  p(true);
  wait;
end process;
 
end behave;
```

Comment: For `p;` IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.5 Subprogram overloading 4.5.1 "A call to an overloaded subprogram is ambiguous (and therefore is an error) if the name of the subprogram, the number of parameter associations, the types and order of the actual parameters, the names of the formal parameters (if named associations are used), and the result type (for functions) are not sufficient to identify
exactly one (overloaded) subprogram."  Both have a single default parameter. Which version of Modelsim? The procedures themselves are not homographs. The call is ambiguous.

Comment: Why the call is ambiguous is that there declarations (definitions) are both visible and not homographs, with one defined in the inner declarative region (the process). See 12.3 Visibility and 12.5 The context of overload resolution.

Comment: I have only tried this in Modelsim PE 10.6c. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: It is also not ambiguous for recent versions of QuestaSim (e.g. 2020.1), so it seems to be a longstanding defect for ModelSim/QuestaSim.

Comment: @user16145658  That only applies if both are visible at the point of calling.   1076-2019 12.3 Visibility says, "A declaration is said to be hidden within (part of) an inner declarative region if the inner region contains a homograph of this declaration; the outer declaration is then hidden within the immediate scope of the inner homograph."

Hence, the declaration in the architecture should be hidden and it is not ambiguous.

Comment: At the point of calling in the unlabeled process in the question both declarations of procedure p are visible in the process statement part, they are not homographs. "Each of two declarations is said to be a homograph of the other if and only if both declarations have the same designator, and they denote different named entities, and either overloading is allowed for at most one of the two, or overloading is allowed for both declarations and they have the same parameter and result type profile". They don't have the same parameter type profile, one integer the other boolean.

Comment: 4.5.1 "If two subprograms overload each other, one of them can hide the other only if both subprograms have the same parameter and result type profile."

Comment: @user16145658   That is unfortunate as some aspects of visibility and  subprogram overloading have to do with the call (such as using named association and distinct parameter names) and this aspect is based on the subprogram declared interface (rather than being based on the calling aspects of the interface).

Comment: ghdl demonstrates the error at being the procedure call on line 18 consisting of `p;`. See 4.5.1 ""A call to an overloaded subprogram is ambiguous ..." in the first comment.

Comment: You can demonstrate it isn't a homograph issue by changing the p call without a parameter in the unlabelled process to `p(2);` showing there is no visibility problem. The issue is instead that of overload resolution, 12.5 The context of overload resolution "At such a place, all visible declarations are considered. The occurrence is only legal if there is exactly one interpretation of each constituent of the innermost *complete context*. ... " The p call without a parameter can't distinguish the two procedures declared with default values.